# Can we include C source file in another way?

Tags: c, eclipse, intel-fpga, bare-metal

I am doing a bare metal project on Cyclone V and now I am trying to make a bare metal application in C. However, I have some issue in including source file.

For example, I use the function `alt_fpga_state_get()` from `alt_fpga_manager.h` but it gives me error message

> "undefined reference to 'atl_fpga_state_get()'

Knowing that it needs a source file containing the function, I import the source file with no problem. However, here come another thing that inside `alt_fpga_manager.c` it also gives an error message

> "undefined reference to 'alt_clock_is_enable'

Then I have to import source file for `alt_clock_manager.h` and the problem keep going on like that until I end up import the whole src folder. After that all the "undefined reference" problem are solved but it come with another problem telling me that my OCRAM is overflowed ( I think because of adding many source file ).

I would like to know if there is any solution for this because keep importing source file is not a convenient way to do. I did look at some examples and I found that in their `makefile` having this line

```
HWLIBS_SRC  := alt_reset_manager.c alt_clock_manager.c alt_spi.c alt_globaltmr.c alt_timers.c alt_watchdog.c
```

I think it is the way they include the source file but I am not sure. Hope someone can give me a clue to solve this problem.

Thanks !

Comment: #include allows to_ declare_ the functions, not to_define_ them, you miss to link with additional object or lib files

Comment: Hi bruno, I understand what you mean and I solved it by importing directly the .c file into my project ( I do not it is a good way ). That way also caused the problem I said in my post. Can you please explain a bit more clearly how to link it or just tell me some source/tutorial to look at? Thanks a lot !

Comment: what do you mean by _importing_ ? if you #include the .c file yes this is not correct. I put an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you `#include` an header file you get the function *declarations* (etc depending on header file contents), that does not *define* them, you missed to link with needed object or lib files

Example :

main.c is

```
#include "f.h"

int main()
{
   f();
}
```

f.h is

```
extern void f();
```

f.c is

```
void f() {}
```

If I just consider *main.c* :

```
/tmp % gcc main.c 
/tmp/ccFs7Gyz.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `f'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

But also considering *f.c* :

```
/tmp % gcc main.c f.c
```

Of course can also do in several steps

```
/tmp % gcc -c f.c
/tmp % gcc main.c f.o
```

etc

P.S. do not *#include* a source file, so no `#include "f.c"` in *mainc.c*

Comment: And take some documentation on the difference between compilation and linking, that will help on understanding the world of compiled languages :)